# JUnit / Mockito: throwing an exception in a new thread

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I have the following Java code that I'm writing unit tests for:

```
try {
    new Thread(() -> myService.myMethod()).start();
    return new MyResponse("Done");
} catch (Exception exception) {
    throw new MyException("Internal Error", exception);
}
```

I'm trying to simulate the throwing of an error by myService.myMethod(), so that it gets picked up in the catch block of the code above and an instance of MyException thrown.

In my JUnit test (using org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner and Mockito), I have mocked MyService and injected it into the unit test as a Spring bean:

```
MyService myService = Mockito.mock(MyService.class);
```

I then tried this to mimic the throwing of an exception by the service:

```
IllegalArgumentException myException = new IllegalArgumentException();
Mockito.doThrow(myException).when(myService).myMethod();
```

... but the exception never gets picked up in the catch block of the method I'm testing.

This presumably has something to do with the fact that the code is using another thread to make the call to myService.myMethod().

Is there any way I can get the exception thrown by myService.myMethod() to be caught correctly?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: What exactly do you expect the code to happen if the method returns having started the thread, and then the exception occurs later in the thread?

Comment: If an exception is thrown by the process in the thread, it should get caught by the catch(), shouldn't it?

Comment: No, it would only be caught if the exception was shown in the tread exciting in the catch block. You are creating a new thread which will run as some point in the future while the current thread will continue with the return and then exit the catch block. You could attach an `uncaughtExceptionHandler` to the new thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make sense that an "outer" Thread can catch an exception in another one. 
If you add context to your code, eg

```
Thread th = new Thread(() -> { Thread.sleep(10000); throw new RuntimeException(); });
try { th.start(); } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("uh-oh");
}
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    System.out.println("running " + i);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

the thread is started and will throw an exception after 10 seconds. However, the starting thread has moved on to counting up every second. If the started thread's exception would be caught, do you expect the main thread to go back to where it catches the exception? Should it interrupt the counting and then continue? not continue?

The best you can do is probably designating an error handler (like Roger mentions in his comment), but you'll have to query its state from the main thread at practical intervals because it will be running in the concurrently started thread.

Considering `t = new Thread(); t.start();` is not recommended to use anymore, the easiest way would be using `CompletableFuture` IMO:

```
CompletableFuture<Void> future = 
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> myService.myMethod());
```

Now you can query later on what happened:

```
if (future.isDone()) // task has finished in any way

if (future.isDone() && future.isCompletedExceptionally()) // task was finished because an exception was thrown
```

Answer (score 0):

How is your code execution orders? First you need to setup your mock, and then run it.

```
MyService myService = Mockito.mock(MyService.class);
Mockito.when(myService.myMethod()).doThrow(myexception.class); // try in this order


try {
    new Thread(() -> myService.myMethod()).start();
    return new MyResponse("Done");
} catch (Exception exception) {
    throw new MyException("Internal Error", exception);
}
```

By the way, if you are working with java 8 or later, you may want to use CompletableFuture package. That is, `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {})`

Comment: The return type of myService.myMethod is void, so unfortunately I can't use your "Mockito.when()" syntax.

Comment: have you tried using the Mockito.mock inside the lambda. ?

Comment: How would I do that, exactly?